# NET 6: 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddOpenTelemetryTracing'

Tags: asp.net-core, open-telemetry

I am working on NET 6 Web Service. After updating all nuget packages to freshest versions I received the error

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddOpenTelemetryTracing' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddOpenTelemetryTracing' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IServiceCollection' could be found

here

```
builder.Services
    .AddOpenTelemetryTracing((builder) => builder
        // Configure the resource attribute `service.name` to MyServiceName
        .SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault().AddService("MyServiceName"))
        // Add tracing of the AspNetCore instrumentation library
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddConsoleExporter()
    );
```

How to fixt it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AddOpenTelemetryTracing` has been removed in favour of `AddOpenTelemetry` in 1.4.0

> Pre-release versions (all versions prior to 1.4.0) of
> OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting contained signal-specific methods for
> configuring tracing and metrics:
>
> AddOpenTelemetryTracing: Configure OpenTelemetry and register an
> IHostedService to automatically start tracing services in the supplied
> IServiceCollection.
>
> AddOpenTelemetryMetrics: Configure OpenTelemetry and register an
> IHostedService to automatically start metric services in the supplied
> IServiceCollection.
>
> These methods were marked obsolete and later removed. You should
> migrate your code to the new AddOpenTelemetry method documented above.
> Refer the old and new versions of the example application to assist
> you in your migration.

Source: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting/CHANGELOG.md#140